# Make 2d edge faded clouds

Tags: game-maker

Hi and sorry If I misunderstood about asking this question here. I'm working with game maker and recently I hit something that I couldn't solve. I have a piece of cloud sprite and I have several cliffs which player walks on them. I want to show the cloud on cliffs in a way that they just render those parts which I will say(the start and end of cliffs) and next the main problem is when the cloud is going to the end of its start place in x vector it will turn to an ugly sliced piece because there isn't anything to make that part fade. I did the first part but for fading I couldn't.

I know it's kinda hard to dig but sorry for that fellas. If you couldn't get what I mentioning I can put an image. For short, I want a trick to make a fade effect on the sliced parts.
[image: The sliced part]

Answer (score 0):

If you have some code, care to show it? - The manner in which one should answer this is very dependent on what you already did.

As for a generic method: let the end & start behave "differently" instead of looping from start to end do something like (say width of platform is W, and cloud width is C - left of platform is X):

```
<draw start cloud, different sprite /options - at position X>
var i;
for (i = X + C; i < W-C; i += C) {
    <draw cloud at x-position i>
}
<draw end cloud at position i + C>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I omitted this in our game but thanks for care.